# Is it possible to create an animated jQuery banner under 40kb?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, banner

Is it possible? If so, how should I proceed. Is there a jQuery version somewhere light enough to achieve this? Should I use a plugin or write my own code?

Another possible option is Flash, but I'm trying to stay away from it since, you know, we're in 2013.

I'm looking to achieve [this kind of animated banner](http://www.angelcarebaby.com/pubs/bannieres/slide-bath.php?a=51773885%E2%80%A6//angelcarebaby.com/item/canada-best-bath-support-for-easy-bath-time/). This one is currently using layerslider, but 379kb is too high. Sizes also vary : 300X250 160X600 728X90 320X50.

Comment: What exactly do you want to use jQuery for in the banner?

Comment: Could you tell me more about this banner requisites?

Comment: Flash is definitely still alive and valid as a solution in 2013. however, in your case, i'm not sure you need anything more than a jpeg.

Comment: Hi guys! I'm looking to achieve this kind of animated banner : http://www.angelcarebaby.com/pubs/bannieres/slide-bath.php?a=51773885%E2%80%A6//angelcarebaby.com/item/canada-best-bath-support-for-easy-bath-time/. This one is currently using layerslider, but 379kb is too high.

Sizes also vary : 

300X250
160X600
728X90
320X50

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S2beY/

Comment: Hm. I'm hoping to achieve this kind of animation : http://www.angelcarebaby.com/pubs/bannieres/slide-bath.php?a=51773885%E2%80%A6//angelcarebaby.com/item/canada-best-bath-support-for-easy-bath-time/